# Gatsby Source Contentful with Variable in Query

Tags: graphql, contentful, gatsby

I'm creating some landing pages on my Gatsby site and want to list nodes from specific content types.  For instance, I have:

```
allContentfulSongs
allContentfulBlogs
```

In my landing page template, how can I dynamically query songs or blogs? I tried:

```
all${landingPage} {
    edges {
      node {
       id
     }
   }
}
```

but I'm getting a syntax error.  Is there a way to do this in Gatsby or should I just use an

```
  @include(if: $landingPage)
```

for each contentType in my query?

Comment: If your landing pages share the same structure maybe you should consider have one content type for them and each landing page can be identified by a unique slug.

Comment: @KhaledGarbaya Thanks. Upon review, I don't think my question was very clear. I do have a separate content type for Landing pages.  When those pages happen to also be a post category, I was trying to pull in a few of the latest records.  So I'm pulling in the basic landing page data, but trying to also pull from another content type dynamically.  I think you're right that maybe I just need to rethink the structure I'm working with rather than go down this road.  Thanks!

Comment: But still you can definitely have multiple queries on your gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use "dynamic" GraphQL queries. So you cannot use a javascript variable as part of your query name in Gatsby.

Queries are treated specially. That's how Gatsby statically compiles your data. Dynamically generated queries would be much harder (or potentially impossible) to cache, so `pageQuery` does not allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!   I did some restructuring to get around the issue.